# Is walking or cycling more popular with tourists in Istanbul?

Tags: bicycles, istanbul

I've almost a day of layover in Istanbul, Turkey in late November.

Is it common for people to explore the city by renting a bike or more popular to walk around the city, and if it is renting a bike are there places that are open late in the night, since my layover starts after sunset?

Comment: I don't expect that you will be able to rent a bike anywhere in Istanbul and riding a bike in Istanbul is a rare and crackbrained adventure. Been there, done that. In the afternoon traffic, I spent some 4 hours for the 20km from the seaside of the airport to the city centre.